# js backspace and counting how many digits

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

i have this code for counting how many digits where entered

```
var tnnod=0;
function telephone(e) {
    if (tnnod<10) {
        var key;
        var keychar;

        if (window.event) {
            key = window.event.keyCode;
        }
        else if (e) {
            key = e.which;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
        keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

if ((key==null) || (key==0) || (key==8) ||  (key==9) || (key==13) || (key==27) ) {
   return true;
}
else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1)) {
    tnnod+=1;
   return true;
}
else if (keychar == "-") { 
  return true;
}
else
   return false;
}
    else
        return false
}
```

but how do i remove 1 from the counter each time the backspace was hitted and the char that was deleted was a digit and not "-"

i have tried getting the key == 8 to do something but hitting the backspace doesn't really return anything for some reason

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to detect specifically the backspace keypress. Try this:

```
var tn_count = 0;
function telephone(ev) {
  var el = document.getElementById("telephone_number");

  if(tn_count < 10) {
    var key, keychar;
    if(window.event) {
      key = window.event.keyCode;
    } else {
      key = ev.which;
    }

    keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
  }

  if(!keychar.match(/\d|-/)) {  // only allow digits or "-"
    return false;
  }

  // clean up any non-digit chars that get in here somehow
  el.value = el.value.replace(/[A-Za-z]+/, '');
  tn_count = el.value.replace("-",'').length; // get the digit length
  return true;
}
```

The basic difference here is that instead of adding 1 every time the key is pressed, just updated `tn_count` to be the total count of all digit characters in the field. You can probably do some more cleanup just to be safe, but this should get you started.

Comment: tommorow i will try the replace and length - then will be able to go with my idea... thanks

Comment: i have used this with a little mod... the el.value and the tn_count lines should be after the var el as well cause then it will not count correctly and in the keychar.match line i have add the key == 13 so enter will submit the form

Comment: Great, glad you were able to use it!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bad idea to count keystrokes for something like that. We're talking about input into a text field, right? What will you do if the user does a paste of some string from the clipboard? What if he uses the mouse to mark some text and delete it? Replace it with one character?

I think it would make a lot more sense to just look at the text from the text field and (if necessary) do some fiddling to ensure proper syntax. Let the user enter whatever he wants, if you find garbage characters you can just replace the text with one that doesn't have those characters. You can also trim the field at this time (no leading or trailing spaces). Also, keeping accurate track of the length becomes as easy as asking for the length of the string returned from the field.

Comment: i do have a regular expression check on submit - i just don't want to give the input maxlength when i don't know with how many dashes the user is going to use in the field. so i want to count 10 digits cause here the telephone can be 9 or 10 and the thamplate can be 1,2 or 3 dashes

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts -

1. Would it be possible to use 3 fields instead of 1? Then you could add the dashes later.
2. If you want to use your current method, you might keep a counter of the dashes that have been typed. Then, on each key stroke, check to see how many dashes are left. If it's different than the previous count, you know they've deleted the dashes.
3. I think it needs to be a bit more robust. What if they put a dash in an odd place within the string?
4. You could also prevent the user from entering all non-numeric characters and insert the dashes at each point of separation. So, insert a dash after 3 and 6 numbers as they are typing.

Comment: 1. it is not possible
2. i was thinking about counting the dashes but i just need to know if the field has exceded the digit length
3. i have regular expression for submit any way
4. but then when they will backspace (delete) - i will have to deal with that as well

Answer (score 0):

Could you just count the length of the string and use that value? Something like the following:

```
function getLen(el) {
    return el.value.replace('-', '').length;
}

alert(getLen(document.getElementById('telephone_number')));
```